# Handling DB failed to connect in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I was wondering if there was a way where I can display a custom view when laravel fails to connect to the database? I have tried googling an answer for this but it really doesn't display anything useful.

I currently get:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

2/2
QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = 1 limit 1)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check your database details in `.env` file.Correct your database connection in `.env` file.It should work for you.

Comment: I don't want to fix it, I purposely broke it to try and display a custom view. My question is, HOW do I display a CUSTOM view.

Comment: what do you mean by custom view?

Comment: can you show your controller code and view path..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`, go to `render` method . You can add the following exception checking to handle `query` and `pdo` exception

```
    if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Database\QueryException) {
        dd($e->getMessage());
        //return response()->view('custom_view');
    } elseif ($e instanceof \PDOException) {
        dd($e->getMessage());
        //return response()->view('custom_view');
    }
```

Replace `dd($e->getMessage());` with your custom code.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way I can do something similar to handle 500 error codes?

Comment: if you want to show a custom view for http error, I think you can put your error files in `views/errors/error_code.blade.php` ( in your case `views/errors/500.blade.php`). Laravel should pull that file automatically. Please accept the answer if it solved your issue.